# public key signing algorithm

Tags: performance, cryptography

I work for a large website. We plan to use authentication tokens that will have to be verified by a large number of applications but is issued by a auth application. I am considering asymmetric instead of symmetric signature schemes to avoid storing secret on a large number of application servers.

I made a list of candidate algorithms - dsa, ecdsa, rsa for which there are crypto providers in Java.

Comparing dsa vs rsa:
dsa has signature that is independent of key strength and is much smaller than rsa signature for equivalent security (rsa 1024/1568 vs dsa 192). However dsa verification (expect verification calls to be 100x issue) is about 10x slower than rsa verification. dsa192 can use just sha1 for digest which may be broken, although I guess I could use Sha234 and truncate output to 192 bits.

A review of dsa vs rsa also brought out other esoteric issues - secrecy of private key in dsa is very reliant on how random the k parameter is, dsa does not support firewalled hashes which is not an issue for us.

Comparing ecdsa vs dsa - ecdsa is slightly faster in signing and verification and I saw a claim that with ecdsa we have confidence that signature will verify (slight concern here). The signature size is same and does not enter into picture.

Since the tokens are sent with every request and we are talking about 40 vs 128/196 bytes before encoding, I am thinking about going with ecdsa-192 with sha2 truncated to 192 bits -  I think the 10x cost is unfortunate but hopefully is dominated by I/O costs.

Appreciate feedback. Let me know what I missed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the encryption type you use is important, but remember that the easiest way for a malicious user to subvert your security is not to break the encryption, but to intercept/steal the key.  Check out Eric Lippert's blog for a good gut check : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: yeah, no argument there and in fact the reason why we are exploring asymmetric despite the overhead.

Comment: @mar: I think the relevant point here is that even an asymmetric system *requires a secure mechanism for distributing public keys*. Do you have such a mechanism? If not, worry about designing that before you stress out about the performance costs too much.

Comment: yes, of course we have several layers of security. I am looking very specifically for someone who has evaluated rsa vs ecdsa/dsa for security/performance for use on some of the largest internet sites. Other concerns although valid are not relevant scope. I also know gnupg made a choice to go with rsa recently.